# Bot Framework startNewDialog Example

Tags: node.js, botframework

Has anyone gotten this to work?  I do not believe it works as written (the patched version of beginDialog is expecting opts to be passed in) and I haven't been able to get it to work yet, just playing with it.

Looks like if I specify to resume it loads the existing session for the user but then when it calls beginDialog nothing happens.

I'm using the Channel Emulator and invoking the proactive dialog via the CustomWebApi link.

Comment: Have you sent an initial message to the bot before using the CustomWebApi link?

Comment: Yes.  To clarify, the example works without the bot adapter as long as you don't care about resuming any dialog that might be interrupted.  But I do.  So I must not be using the adapter the way it was intended or it just doesn't work. I'm simply calling patch(bot) and then trying to change as little as possible in the example code to keep it working.

Comment: From where are you getting the sample?

Comment: The BotBuilder samples on Github

Comment: I think the main issue there is that botadapter.js shouldn't be there and shouldn't be used in the sample. That was a patch for an older version of the botbuilder sdk I think. Try without using the adapter.

Comment: Yeah it works without the botadapter but if the user was in a dialog when the proactive dialog is initiated, they can't resume it afterwards.

I've had a lot of time to think about this since initially running across the problem in July and I think I've decided the sending a proactive dialog sounds great in an ideal world, but if your user is already in a dialog either knocking them out of it and letting them resume OR knocking them out of it completely is just a bad user experience.  

I think I'll just stop pursuing this.  But I do thank you for your input!